# How do I check the time remaining in a song without enabling Advanced HUD?

Tags: beat-saber

I am looking for a way to check how much time is left in during a song in Beat Saber. I know there is an [Advanced HUD](https://www.reddit.com/r/beatsaber/comments/d5jmmy/psa_there_is_an_advanced_hud_option_on_the_left/) that includes a song timer, but enabling it also displays your current song ranking and note hit percentage.

Is there a way to check how far I am in a song without enabling the ranking display that comes with Advanced HUD?